# Error converting datetime using date2num in netCDF4 Python

Tags: python, datetime, netcdf, netcdf4

I am trying to write a netcdf file using netCDF4 in Python. For that, I am creating a time variable. I created the time data using `datetime`. I am getting an error when I try to convert the datetime data to netcdf formats using `date2num`.

```
dates=[datetime.datetime(1996,1,1) + relativedelta(months=mon) for mon in range(120)]
```

The above command gives me list of dates that look like-

```
[datetime.datetime(1996, 1, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1996, 2, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1996, 3, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1996, 4, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1996, 5, 1, 0, 0),
 ...
 datetime.datetime(2005, 10, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2005, 11, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2005, 12, 1, 0, 0)]
```

I am using the following command to convert the date to netCDF4 dates:

`dates_nc=nc.date2num(dates,time.units)`

Here `time.units` is `since 1991-01-01` (I am not sure how time.units works)

The `nc.date2num` command gives the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
cftime\_cftime.pyx in cftime._cftime._datesplit()

ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-154-97a05959ce3c> in <module>
----> 1 dates_nc=nc.date2num(dates,time.units)

cftime\_cftime.pyx in cftime._cftime.date2num()

cftime\_cftime.pyx in cftime._cftime._dateparse()

cftime\_cftime.pyx in cftime._cftime._datesplit()

ValueError: Incorrectly formatted CF date-time unit_string
```

What could be the reason for the error?

Answer (score 1):

You need add the time units example:
`days since 1991-01-01`

Can be days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds or microseconds.
https://unidata.github.io/cftime/api.html#cftime.date2num

Comment: I have monthly data, how can I add months?

Comment: https://github.com/Unidata/cftime/blob/master/cftime/_cftime.pyx#L172
    **units**: a string of the form **<time units> since <reference time>**
    describing the time units. **<time units>** can be days, hours, minutes,
    seconds, milliseconds or microseconds. **<reference time>** is the time
    origin. **months_since** is allowed *only* for the **360_day** calendar.

Comment: Example:  `nc.date2num(dates, 'months since 2020-08-01', '360_day')`